# Change color in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

Ok, it force me to write something else. I dont know javascrip and i want to make webhook thar will send all from google form to discord and i want to change color of the strip that make this webhook.

I found code, but i dont know javascript at all. Can someone help me to change color to #A200FF here:

```
var webhook = "*here my webhook URL*"; //Your webhook URL from Discord.
var title = "Test"; //The title of your embed, example: "Punishment Log"
var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215) || 14508118 //Random Color

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /* Optional ticket counter at end of title */
                  /* Example: #0001 */

let activate = true; //If you want this, change "false" to "true"
// If enabled, and you have a custom title, it'll look like this: "Punishment Log #0001"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /* If you do not understand coding,
          please don't tamper with the code below! */
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////





function embedSubmitUpdated(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var allResponses = form.getResponses();
  var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
  var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
  var items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = response[i].getResponse();
    var parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
    if (answer == "") continue;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      if (j == 0) items.push({ "name": question, "value": parts[j], "inline": false });
      else items.push({ "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"), "value": parts[j], "inline": false });
    }}


  if(activate == true) {
    let count = allResponses.length;
    if(count < 1000) count = (`000${count}`).slice(-4);
    if(!title) title = "Punishment Appeal";
    var options = {"method": "post", "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json"}, muteHttpExceptions: true, "payload": JSON.stringify({ "embeds": [{
    "title": title + " #" + count, "color": color,
    "fields": items, "timestamp": new Date().toISOString(),}]})};
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  } else {
    var options = {"method": "post", "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json"}, muteHttpExceptions: true, "payload": JSON.stringify({ "embeds": [{
    "title": title || "Punishment Appeal", "color": color,
    "fields": items, "timestamp": new Date().toISOString(),}]})};
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhook, options);
  }
};
```

Comment: `var color = "#A200FF";`

Comment: Then, you'll probably want to apply that color to some DOM element.  If you give us a minimal working example (snippet), someone can help you further. Go here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added full version of code, can you help, because he dont want to send messeges this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, it appears that it wants the color in decimal format rather than hexadecimal.

[Converting](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html) **#A200FF** to decimal yields: **10617087**

So try setting `color` to 10617087.

```
var color = 10617087;
```